# python pandas crosstab: error to show percentage with more than one column

Tags: python, pandas, crosstab

I am trying to create a crosstab with more than one column. It is created correctly with the following code:

```
crt= pd.crosstab(index=df.hc_est, columns=[df.year_iq,df.group], margins=True)

year_iq         2017           2018       All
cir_grup    inter   prim    inter   prim    
hc_est                  
IA              0   10          1   11     22
IC              0    4          0    0     4
IC1             0    0          0    1     1
....
IVA             4    1          2    0     7
IVB             1    0          1    0     2
All            13   20         12   19     64
```

I would like to add a percentage column to each column (including the 'All' column). To do this I try to create the same crosstab with the percentages and then make a join between the two crosstabs.

But it shows error when I set the normalize parameter:

```
crt= pd.crosstab(index=df.hc_est, columns=[df.year_iq,df.group], margins=True, normalize=True)
TypeError: Expected tuple, got str

crt= pd.crosstab(index=df.hc_est, columns=[df.year_iq,df.group], margins=True, normalize='columns')
ValueError: Length of new names must be 1, got 2
```

The 'all' option also gives the error: "TypeError: Expected tuple, got str
"

```
dtypes: 
hc_est                object
year_iq               Int64
group                 object
```

Why is it failing? Is there another way to add percentages to all columns based on the total of each column?